# Change font size in ListView - Android/Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

How can I change the font size in a ListView element? In my main.xml file, I have tried several different values in for android:textSize (pt,px,sp,dp) and nothing seems to change it.

Here is what I have currently for the  in my main.xml:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#000080" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px" 
    android:textSize="8px"/>
```

Here is my Java:

```
package com.SorenWinslow.TriumphHistory;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class TriumphHistory extends ListActivity {
    String[] HistoryList;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        HistoryList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.history);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,HistoryList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

2 ways to go:

1. Copy `simple_list_item_1.xml` from Android sources, modify it and then use it instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`;
2. Use `BaseAdapter` and modify font size in `getView(..)` call.

I'd suggest you go with latter.

Comment: How do i define where to change the size in get view?

Comment: As Alex has suggested, it makes sense to override the Adapter's getView() method. I use this approach and it works well.

Comment: I used option 1 since all I don't need to do much, over riding getView method sounds like an overkill IMO

Comment: This is an incomplete answer at best. There is no mention of the method to call (setTextSize); the View object in the adapter is a ListView object, not the TextView associated with it; therefore 'setTextSize' is not a method against that view; if you figure that out and call 'findViewById' against the view you have to get the associated TextView, it shows an error when you try to use "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1' as the id; etc. etc. Not sure why this answer was selected or upvoted as it would require a dozen follow-on questions to actually get something to work.

Answer (score 58):

Go into layout create a new xml file named mylist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@android:id/text1"  
        android:paddingTop="2dip" 
        android:paddingBottom="3dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

now in the code

```
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,HistoryList);
```

change it to

```
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,R.layout.mylist,HistoryList);
```

Comment: This solution does not work when I am trying to make a radio list out of the same, any ideas about that?

Comment: @GarimaTiwari What seems to be the problem ? what is the unexpected behavior you get when you try to do it ?

Answer (score 6):

Please create another file named list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:textSize="21sp">
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that you can only change the text size by using your own layout rather than the android.R.layout.simple_list_item one. By doing that you can change the TextView properties such as the text size. However if you haven't worked with lists with your own layouts, they can appear a bit complex to use the first time. I'll try to come back and edit this answer to provide more information later, but I suggest you look for tutorials on custom list views - that will show you how to `inflate` your own layout files.

Answer (score 0):

Create another xml file for the Text that should be in the list rows..

and just add android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"   in your TextView :D  (put it in a relative layout rather than a linear layout)

and then use your previous ListView xml for the setContentView(R.layout.listview)

and the other xml file in your ArrayAdapter code

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.yoursecondLayoutforthelistswithText, R.id.titles, HistoryList)

the R.id.titles is the id for the TextView

Answer (score -1):

you can save font size in sharedprefs and then recreate your adapter

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    ed.putFloat("fontTwosize", sizeTwo);
    ed.commit();

    adapterz = new LazyziyaratAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    ziyaratList);

    listz.setAdapter(adapterz);
```

and in your getview method of adapter

```
 holder.text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,G.mSharedPreferences.getFloat("fontTwosize", 25));
```