# how to change the Font size of Listview content

Tags: android

i need to customise the Listview...esspecialy like reduce the font size... bcz it occupies more space..how can i reduce listview size... kindly assist me asap...

Comment: you want to reduce the fontsize of text written in listview.

Comment: Similar question can be found here: [change-font-size-in-listview-android-eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464056/change-font-size-in-listview-android-eclipse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can go through this [excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) for doing all fancy on List Views.