# Fonts used in Api Demo

Tags: android

I am trying to get the same look and feel as the API demo in my application, but the fonts appear smaller. I have not set any fonts for my application. Is there some settings i am missing on the fonts?
[image: Api Demo]

[image: My Application]

The image with black background is the Api Demo which came along with the SDK samples. I am working on Android 2.2. The image with the white background is my application. I would like to know how to achieve the spacing between each of the rows in the list and the font as in the API Demos list.Can someone kindly help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Which* API demo? You should post a screenshot to better point out which fonts you're referring to.

Comment: not understandable.. what is your problem

Comment: Which Api , Which SDK , Fonts Where ( controls ? )

Comment: @dmon: I was referring to the API Demo which came as a part of the SDK Samples. I have also posted the screenshot.

Comment: @Pragna: I have provided more information on what my problem is. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @Synxmax: I am working on API Level 8, Android 2.2. I was referring to the fonts in the list as shown in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/MyListView"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
  android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"/>

[1][1] [2][2]
```

[view this link for change font in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464056/change-font-size-in-listview-android-eclipse)