# How to change size of text in application settings?

Tags: android, textview, android-theme, android-textattributes

In my application I want to provide an option to the  give to user to choose the size of text, Is it possible??

And how can I do it?? Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be on first screen of your app can be a screen where user selects the text size may be a single choice list. And this size you can save in as your Application Data or may be preferences and use throughout your application.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12591991/746347

Answer (score 1):

Yes, why not? You can save an int entered by the user and set the size of the textview programmatically to this int.

Comment: yes, but so, i must `setTextSize()` for each textView, editText, etc.. and then i must take in the code the item that i create in xml.. it's right?

Comment: Yes, i don't belive there's a possibility to set the text size "global" but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

## A

A

if user select small A then change it to font 16sp if user select big A then change font size to 21sp.

```
if(small)
textView.setTextSize(16);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can allow user to select from font list view and to create list view of font selection you can check [Change font size in ListView - Android/Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464056/change-font-size-in-listview-android-eclipse) for details.

More on that you can http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/ for details.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can add spinner with list of fontsize

like

```
12
14
16
18
```

and in `onItemSelect()` set fontSize(x);

Answer (score 0):

its possible.
refer [this link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_dynamically_change_font_size_in_Web_Runtime_widgets) or even you can use input type for getting value from user then create a function with parameter "size" and change **css "font-size"** using this function.